# MarkLogic Custom Rest Endpoint set Access-Control-Allow-Origin for preflight request

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I am setting in my custom rest endpoint the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", but when I call this webservice from javascript, I get the following error

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://10.239.12.22:8042/LATEST/resources/repoUIFacet?rs:q=TNF. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://gprulcd707873.abbvienet.com:8000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.
```

Following is the code where I set the response header

```
(: Function responding to GET method - must use local name 'get':)
declare function repoUIFacet:get($context as map:map, $params  as map:map) as document-node()*
{
    let $output-types := map:put($context,"output-types","application/json")

    let $_ := xdmp:add-response-header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    ...
};
```

How do I set the response header for an OPTIONS request ?

Answer (score 2):

The error message ends with `The response had HTTP status code 401`. This is an issue with authentication, not with the access control header. You need to send credentials, or switch the app server to application-level authentication.

HTH!

Comment: No, I think you had an auth failure on the preflight request. Makes sense though, all requests to MarkLogic need to be authenticated normally, so also preflight requests. Putting a proxy or a middle-tier in between like in your answer is a good solution to bypass such auth checks..

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar issue lately. On issuing a request from the browser, the browser sends an additional OPTIONS request to MarkLogic. However my router checked for an api_key and if it didn't exists I responded with a 40x code.

What worked was respsonding with a 200 code whenever the incoming method is OPTIONS before checking the api key. All other methods check the api and return the appropriate response code.

e.g. if you are using an xquery router, you could try something like this:

```
let $method := fn:lower-case(xdmp:get-request-method())

(: Intercept OPTIONS method and respond immediately :)
if ($methods = 'options') then 
    xdmp:set-response-code(200, 'OK')
else (:
    invoke the endpoint function "$method", e.g. repoUIFacet:get
:)
```

Good luck!

Comment: I did not see OPTIONS , for custom rest-api in MarkLOGIC.. I was looking at rewriter.xml and they do not dispatch request for OPTIONS.. But I was able to front marklogic rest api with an apache server and set the CORS on apache , instead of writing a wrapper..

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is interested, Following is what I did instead of writing a custom webservice layer in front of MarkLogic custom rest-api.. 
  I basically have an Apache server that acts as proxy to custom Marklogic endpoints. Then I set the CORS header for it.. And also catch the OPTIONS request and send a 200.. Just letting you know, that when the request has Authorization. the '*' `Access-Control-Allow-Origin *`, will not work.. you need to specify the hosts.. I did a workaround of putting a regular expression, following is how I do it in my apache config or .htaccess file

```
 <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    SetEnvIf Origin "^http(s)?://(.+\.)?(YOUR_DOMAIN.com)(:[0-9]+)?$" origin_is=$0
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{origin_is}e env=origin_is
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
    Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "X-Requested-With, content-type, Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Authorization, X-User-Id"
  </IfModule>

  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]

  ProxyPass /cr_dev http://10.239.12.22:8042/LATEST/resources
  ProxyPassReverse /cr_dev/ http://10.239.12.22:8042/LATEST/resources
```